# Undefined control sequence for \NormalTok or \SpecialCharTok

Tags: r, tinytex

I am using a template to write my thesis (https://github.com/ryanpeek/aggiedown) in latex. I have everything installed however, when I run bookdown (`bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', aggiedown::thesis_pdf(latex_engine = 'xelatex'))`) to knit the template I receive this error:

```r
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...}}\NormalTok { pkg[}\SpecialCharTok 
                                                  {!}\NormalTok {(pkg }\Spec...
l.369 ...onTok{installed.packages}\NormalTok{())]}
```

I thought it was due to a missing package and I tried installing them but it turns out they are not packages.

Comment: It's difficult to debug code we cannot see… Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and edit your question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: a quickgoogle search shows the command defined hre so (probably) you want this package https://github.com/yaqwsx/bcthesis/blob/master/markdownsyntax.sty#L15

Comment: although the template you link to defines most of that aready so just add the missing line it's a trivial definition just giving a colour https://github.com/ryanpeek/aggiedown/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/thesis/skeleton/template.tex#L73